# Strange Bug with Mobile Side Menu and Joomla! template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla3.0

I don't know if this is a real issue since I am seeing it mostly when using an emulator, but it seems to be reproducible, and I noticed it on a friend's Android device.  URL is:

[Link To Page](http://marinasol.com/component/osproperty/beautiful-town-view-condo-001)

On some devices, particular iPad Retina emulator, when you click on the hamburger it moves the body of the page to the right as expected, but the side menu area is completely blank, despite the fact that there are elements there and you can click on them, they just are not showing up, so they are being rendered but the whole sidebar is just blank (see picture)

[image: iPad Retina]

I did discover a useful feature on the developer menu with Safari that I was not aware of.  You can go to Develop -> Simulator and use the inspector for the page that is loaded in your simulator.  Quite a nice feature, but still not able to quite figure out what the issue is.

It is using a Joomla! template and looking at the source seems like it could use a lot of tweaking because there are a ton of .css and .js resources, some of which probably are not needed and some which probably conflict with one another, some which are not needed on the front end, etc.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I posted there as well.

Comment: I think I figured out what the issue is but I don't see how to fix it.  It looks like is has to do with the z-index of the side menu element.  For some reason the left margin of the body is acting like it has a higher z-index value than the side menu.  Not sure how to fix it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of a fix:

```
body.jsn-menu-mobile-push-left {
        margin-left: 0px;
}
```

but not ideal.  It shows the menu in this case but it doesn't slide out the body to the right.  That is a little strange since when the margin-left is set to 0px it doesn't display.

Comment: I actually was able to fix this, not sure exactly how, but it may have been related to prepending an element in the DOM with jQuery somehow and messing up z-index.  Working now.